How to install a door in a bathroom?
I have a bathroom in my house that does not have a door (see attached picture). I want to install a custom door to it since it a very tall opening, measuring roughly 96" x 34.5". I have a few questions around how to go about it. I spoke to the Home Depot guys and they suggested that I can order a custom/special order pre-hung door for my project.
I still have a few more questions about the process:

All the videos I saw had the rough opening with stud showing. Do I need to scrape/rip the drywall to install the door or can I install it over the existing wall as it is?

Do I need to buy the casing separately to match the current one? If yes what is the exact name/type of the casing that I should ask for (see the second picture attached).

Many videos I saw show the casing is premade (like an L-shaped bracket that fits snugly in the door frame, but could not find any such thing at Home Depot).


Door opening where I want to install the door

Existing door (to match the trim/casing)


I revised your post formatting a bit for clarity and brevity. To the third bulleted point, I'm not sure what you're asking there. First, make sure you understand the terms you're using. The jamb is the frame around the door to which hinges attach. The casing is the trim molding on the wall. Please revise to clarify that question (and make it an actual question).

Look for a specialty door place… in >20 years, I’ve had a good door experience at Home Depot exactly once, with numerous fails. Expect better quality and better price from a specialty place.

You've asked a mouthful here, which sorta makes your question off topic. I'll address the questions generally, and you'll need to ask additional questions to get more detail.
Do I need to scrape/rip the drywall to install the door?
No. Your opening width is appropriate for a 2-8 (32") door as it is. What you should do, though, is remove the corner bead and scrape off some of the built-up drywall mud there so you have a more standard 4-1/2" wall thickness. That's what your new jamb will be sized for, and a thicker wall makes casing it more challenging.
Do I need to buy the casing separately to match the current one?
I'm not sure if you actually mean casing here (the trim on the wall), or the door jamb. To the former, yes, but I can't tell what style you have. Take a clear closeup photo with you to the store. To the latter, you'll buy a paint-grade prehung door in your desired style (flat, raised panel, etc.), which will include the jamb.

The steps you'll follow to accomplish this task go like this, broadly speaking:

Remove the interfering base trim. This can be reused if you're gentle. You'll need to pull nails through from the back side and sand any rough edges flat.

Remove the rounded corner bead as described above.

Frame the opening down to standard door height (jamb height plus about 1/2").  Do this with a 2x4 across the top, short 2x4 studs on each side, and a doubled 2x4 under them. Screw everything together with 3" general purpose screws (flute-head, like drywall screws).

Install drywall on the new framing and finish it (tape, prime, paint). Note that this isn't a putty knife job. Use a wide knife (12" or so) and taper out well. Apply mud in thin layers. Sanding should be for final smoothness, not shape.

Install your door and hardware. Make sure you understand how to achieve plumb, level, and square.

Install casing and reinstall base moldings, then prime and paint them. Optionally pre-paint your new moldings.


Each of these steps could amount to a tutorial by itself, so do some reading and post new questions as needed.

+1. A thought: Home Depot and Lowes, at least, have 32" x 96" doors available. OP may be able to skip the framing down and drywalling.

8' doors look weird in a house with no others. I'd much rather have a standard door.

True, but both of OP's pictures show 96" door openings. They both scale to the doorway being 89% of the ceiling height, and OP says the doorway into the bathroom is 96, so the other door would be also. I'm deducing the same floor for both openings, therefore same ceiling height, as shown by the similar flooring, base molding, and paint.
